# LESS not working in ASP.NET Web Tools 2012.2

Tags: css, visual-studio, less

I recently upgraded Visual Studio 2012 with the ASP.NET Web Tools 2012.2 update which made LESS files first-class citizens in VS. However, since the upgrade, changes to my .less files aren't converted to .css and .css.min. Also, I don't get the CSS preview pane anymore when I edit my .less files.

I've uninstalled/reinstalled and tried to repair the installation. Any ideas?

Comment: No, not yet. I moved on to another project that isn't using LESS but I'd still like to get an answer.

Comment: I ended up just installing SimpLESS and letting it monitor my project and compile the css files.

Answer (score 0):

According to this question ([VS2012.2 LESS Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474285/vs2012-2-less-support)) Visual Studio 2012 provides first class support for LESS but you still need to install [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) to get the compiler integrated.