# VS2012.2 LESS Support

Tags: visual-studio, less, web-essentials

Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 was released recently with " first-class support for editing LESS files, complete with syntax highlighting, Intellisense, and validation".

Does Update 2 also include support for compiling LESS, or do I still need a separate Add-In to do that (for example Web Essentials)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS 2012 Update 2 includes LESS editor support. You still have to install Web Essentials to get the compiler support.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

Comment: Thanks for confirming Fammy.